# "Reversed" use of fct_infreq() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used `fct_infreq()` to reorder mpg's model factor levels by frequency.
However, the provided code results in a plot where the factor with least counts will appear at the top of the plot. I would like to have it the opposite way, so that the most frequent factor will appear at the top. Is there a way to do that?

`ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = fct_infreq(model))) +
  coord_flip()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(model)))) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

BTW, [as of ggplot 3.3.0 from March 2020](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#rewrite-of-axis-code), `coord_flip` is no longer necessary in most situations -- you can directly map to the axis you want:

```
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(y = fct_rev(fct_infreq(model))))
```